# возвращение на ту же позицию страницы через header('Location: ../index.php')

Tags: javascript, php

У меня есть ссылка `<a href='code.php'>link</a>` которая ведет к выполнению кода написанного в файле `code.php`, в конце этого файла у меня есть переадресация (`header('Location: ../index.php')`) на страницу с ссылкой.
Можно ли в какой то способ вернуться на страницу с ссылкой на ту позицию, где я ее нажал?

Comment: попробуйте присвоить ссылке `id`, чтобы создать якорь, а в `location` укажите `index.php#ваш_айди'

Comment: Я бы сделал через возврат кода 204, но кажется у него есть проблемы в iOS

Comment: @highpassion сделал как вы сказали, и вроде как то работает, то есть возвращаеться к этому элементу, но все равно ставит его на самом верху страницы, то есть на половину уже хорошо, но все же я не получаю точно ту позицию

Comment: что значит "ставит его на самом верху страницы"? вы хотите сказать, что у вас на самом верху страницы сразу же элемент, а вам нужен еще отступ сверху?

Comment: да, он просто эту ссылку ставит на самый верх, хотя когда я нажимал ее, то она не была на самом верху